# CodeIgniter select query date difference

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

How can I implement the below query in PHP CodeIgniter?

What I am doing is selecting `id` from `approval`, where `level = 5` and datetime must be compared with current datetime.

If a number of days goes above 30 days and below 61 days I need to fetch `ID`.

```
SELECT ID FROM APPROVAL WHERE Level = 5 AND DateTime >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY AND DateTime < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 61 DAY;
```

I have tried,

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('approval');
$this->db->where('level'=>5);
$this->db->where('date_and_time'>= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY);
$this->db->where('date_and_time'< CURDATE() + INTERVAL 61 DAY);
$res=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

It's not executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for ur help guys this one is working :)

```
            $this->db->select('id');
            $this->db->from('approval');
            $this->db->where("level = '5'");
            $this->db->where("DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_and_time) BETWEEN 30 AND 60");         

            $pending=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is not correct.

Try

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('approval');
$this->db->where('level'=>5);
$this->db->where('date_and_time >=', "CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY", false);
$this->db->where('date_and_time <', "CURDATE() + INTERVAL 61 DAY", false);
$res=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

The third parameter `false` of the function `where` is here to prevent CI to consider your date calculation as a field name and in consequence not adding surroundings "`"

See CI's documentation : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?#CI_DB_query_builder::where

Comment: Thanks for u reply, but its not executing sir :(

Comment: $res = $this->db->select('id')->get_where('approval',array('level'=>5,'date_and_time >=' => "CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY",'date_and_time <' => "CURDATE() + INTERVAL 61 DAY"))->result_array();    I tried this one too its executing but it doesnt give any results.

Answer (score 1):

Here `now()` is current date. `>=1` is difference between table stored value and current date.

Before doing this you should load date helper `$this->load->helper('date');`

```
$this->db->select("*", FALSE);
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where("DATEDIFF(your_date,now()) >= 1");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Otherwise simply you can use like below:

```
$this->db->select("*", FALSE);
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where("DATEDIFF(your_date,now())");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make helper for easier to Re-use.

```
function where_between($field, $min, $max){
   $CI = get_instance();
   return $CI->db->where("$field BETWEEN $min AND $max");
}
```

> Load Helper of your saved name from /application/helpers/

```
$this->load->helper('yoursaved_helper');
//
$this->db->where_between('date_and_time', 30, 61);
```

> OR you can use Directly

```
$this->db->where("date_and_time BETWEEN 30 AND 61");
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in you query where condition, check the condition inside single quote and comma after condition and value, for [reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)     and in this line `$this->db->where('level=>', "5");` you have `>` symbol after equal sign, it should be like `>=` or simply `=` like below

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('approval');
$this->db->where('level=', "5");
$this->db->where('date_and_time>=', "CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY");
$this->db->where('date_and_time<', "CURDATE() + INTERVAL 61 DAY");
$res=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: thk u for ur reply, here date_and_time is an timestamp in my database, will the above condition work for timestamp also.

Comment: yes date value condition will work with timestamp column, check with above code, it will work

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude, but this way is working for me. $this->db->where("level = '5'");

Comment: Check my updated answer it will also work, i think you have varchar for column `level`, so then we have to use quotes for value `"5"`, make it accept answer if it works to help others.